# Как реализовать прокрутку до элемента с помощью scrollTop при body {zoom:90%} ?

Tags: масштабирование, прокрутка

Здравствуйте.

Сайт http://marvelestate.ru.
На сайте реализована прокрутка до блока с ID по клику на пункт меню.

```
$('.main_menu a').click(function () {
     var elementClick = $(this).attr('href');
     var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
     $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination  }, 1000);
     return false;
});
```

Все работает, все ок. Но по прошествии некоторого времени заказчику захотелось изменить масштаб, задав

```
body {
  zoom: 90%;
}
```

Теперь, соответственно, скролл работает некорректно. Как привязать скролл к масштабированию?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте нативный js метод получения отступа, пример http://jsfiddle.net/dvxeyyxp/1/

--js

```
$('a').click(function () {
     var destination = document.getElementById($(this).attr('href')).offsetTop;
     $('body').animate({ scrollTop: destination  }, 1000);
     return false;
 });
```

Comment: Получаю Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null 
И в вашем примере тоже.

Comment: Понял, в чем проблема. Спасибо вам огромное. Работает.

Comment: Всегда рад, исправил пример